# Aliased Signal's Frequency

Tags: frequency, aliasing

So I have an incoming signal of `137.9 MHz` and a sampling frequency of `1.4 MHz`. Once sampled how do I calculate the aliased signal's new frequency? Bandwidth is `38 kHz` with a subcarrier of `2400 Hz`, if that information is relevant. Just looking for an equation to calculate the aliased frequency.

The hardware used is a *RTL-SDR* into a computer sampling at `1.4 MSPS`.

This is the signal's information page:

https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Automatic_Picture_Transmission_(APT)

Comment: If you're using RTL-SDR or some other SDR, it is almost surely doing some frequency shifting before the sampler. Can you clarify what your setup is?

Comment: @MBaz Just update it

Comment: OK, so the SDR is doing band-pass filtering and frequency shifting. You shouldn't have any aliases. If you have any, they depend on which signals are in the passband of your BPF, and your intermediate frequency.

Comment: Look at this document if helps: https://aaronscher.com/wireless_com_SDR/RTL_SDR_AM_spectrum_demod.html

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you!